# Keep input field in view while using on-screen keyboard

Tags: qt, qml

I've a virtual keyboard which pops-up from the bottom of the screen and always stays on top. I'm going to use this in my application and have a small problem.

If the text input field which accepts input from this keyboard is in middle / bottom of the view (main window / screen), it gets hidden behind the keyboard i.e., can't see whats been entered until the keyboard is hidden.

Keyboard is running as `platforminputcontext` plugin which will know the field that is accepting the input.

```
void KeyboardPlatformInputContext::setFocusObject(QObject* object)
{
    qDebug() << m_focusedObject << object;
    m_focusedObject = object;
}
```

When the keys are pressed, they are passed as `QEvents` like this

```
void KeyboardPlatformInputContext::processNormalKeyClick(const QString& key)
{
    qDebug() << m_focusedObject << key;
    if (m_focusedObject) {
        QInputMethodEvent inputEvent;
        inputEvent.setCommitString(key);
        QGuiApplication::sendEvent(m_focusedObject, &inputEvent);
    }
}
```

Now, with the available information (`m_focusedObject` and `QGuiApplication`) can it be possible to do something to keep the input field in view. Always.

Comment: First of all you'll need a mechanism to move the entirety of your UI around. You have to figure out what will work in your particular use-case. Then use that to move things so that the focused control is visible, iff it wasn't to start with.

Answer (score 6):

Kuba has the right idea; I'll just expand on it. You can use [`Flickable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html), for example, to manage the content of your application. For example, suppose your application was laid out like a form:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: root
    width: 480
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20
        spacing: 20

        Repeater {
            model: 20

            Row {
                spacing: 20

                Text {
                    text: "Input #" + (index + 1)
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
                TextInput {
                    width: 100
                    height: 30

                    onActiveFocusChanged: {
                        if (activeFocus)
                            keyboardRect.visible = activeFocus
                    }

                    Rectangle {
                        border.width: 1
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        anchors.margins: -1
                        z: -1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: keyboardRect
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.3
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        color: "grey"
        visible: false
    }
}
```

To make it usable with a virtual keyboard, move the content into a `Flickable`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: root
    width: 480
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20
        anchors.bottomMargin: keyboardRect.visible ? keyboardRect.height : anchors.margins
        contentWidth: column.implicitWidth
        contentHeight: column.implicitHeight
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick

        Column {
            id: column
            spacing: 20

            Repeater {
                model: 20

                Row {
                    spacing: 20

                    Text {
                        text: "Input #" + (index + 1)
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    }
                    TextInput {
                        width: 100
                        height: 30

                        onActiveFocusChanged: {
                            if (activeFocus) {
                                keyboardRect.visible = activeFocus

                                var posWithinFlickable = mapToItem(column, 0, height / 2);
                                flickable.contentY = posWithinFlickable.y - flickable.height / 2;
                            }
                        }

                        Rectangle {
                            border.width: 1
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            anchors.margins: -1
                            z: -1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: keyboardRect
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.3
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        color: "grey"
        visible: false
    }
}
```

A few things to note:

```
anchors.bottomMargin: keyboardRect.visible ? keyboardRect.height : anchors.margins
```

This ensures that the content is "pushed" up when the keyboard is visible, so that nothing is hidden below it.

```
onActiveFocusChanged: {
    if (activeFocus) {
        keyboardRect.visible = activeFocus

        var posWithinFlickable = mapToItem(column, 0, height / 2);
        flickable.contentY = posWithinFlickable.y - flickable.height / 2;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't account for losing focus and hence the keyboard always stays open.

We focus the `Flickable` on the current input field by mapping the position of the field to the `Column`.

Finally, you'll see a bit of jumping around when you click on the fields near the top or bottom of the column. This can be probably solved by not setting the `contentY` if the field is near the top or bottom. An exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: For me correct answer is Yours plus following:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-deployment-guide.html#creating-inputpanel

Answer (score 1):

For me correct answer is above (first one) plus following:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-deployment-guide.html#creating-inputpanel

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1

Item {
    id: root
    Item {
        id: appContainer
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: inputPanel.top
        ...
    }
    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        y: Qt.inputMethod.visible ? parent.height - inputPanel.height : parent.height
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
    }
}
```

**Quote:**

> The input panel must be a sibling element next to the application
>   container. It is important not to put the input panel within the
>   application container, as it would then overlap with the contents of
>   the application. Also, the input panel height will be automatically
>   updated according to the available width; the aspect ratio of the
>   input panel is constant.